# accessing file system in javascript or jquery or angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have a web application whose purpose is to upload some excel files and images related to that excel file. Now for example if directory structure on client side is as follows

```
..
  /education.xls
  /educationImages
      /img1.png
      /img2.png
```

can I write a code in javascript/jquery/angularjs so that if user selects education.xls for upload, my script would automatically attach img1 and img2 with that form data ?

Comment: We now have a FIleSystem API for web. Please see https://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/file_access

Comment: this api relies on user to select files? or it can read files without user selection?

Comment: taking a look [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) reveals that you can explore the FileSystem with API itself. Considering your use case, it is possible to read the related image files after user selects the xls file to upload.

Comment: @sid-m, [support in Chrome only and unlikely to be adopted by other browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem).

Comment: There are security issues with that. Users don't want evil websites grabbing things from their filesystem without their knowledge.

Comment: @georgeawg well I guess in my case I can ask user to select folder. Once folder is selected then I can fetch all files / folders inside that ... right?